# select all option for dropdown using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am totally fed up of this coding part just to add select all option, i have successfully added select all, but the problem is how to fetch the data, from mysql database using, for that select all option.

i have 8 tables in ma database and for search box i have to select the table for query search term for which it will show information for query term from selected table.

here is the code for above:

```
<form method="post" action="test3.php" name="search_form">
 <input type="text" name="search" size=15 maxlength=15 placeholder = "Gene Symbol"/>
        <select name="table[]" id = "table[]" size = "0" multiple>
            <option selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="infla_info">Inflammation</option>
            <option value="diet_info">diet</option>
            <option value="obesity_info">obesity</option>
            <option value="stress_info">stress</option>
            <option value="athero_info">atherosclerosis</option>
            <option value="retino_info">Diabetic Retinopathy</option>
            <option value="nephro_info">Diabetic Nephropathy</option>
            <option value="neuro_info">Diabetic Neuropathy</option>
        </select>
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Gene Search"/>
```

here value = table name, for each table it is working, for multiple tables also its working, but when its time to select all its totally fail. 
i have added select all option too,, but as it is not working for in fetching.

can anyone suggest how can i select the search term in all tables of mysql database? this would be beneficial for select all option i think. and secondly what should be there in value = "" for select all option.

```
case "infla_info":
  //echo "<h1> Inflammation </h1>";

  $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from infla_info where Gene_symbol = '$search'");
  $num_row=$sql->num_rows;

  if ($num_row == 0)
  {
    echo "<font color = 'red'>Gene not found in Inflammation.</font>";
  }
  else
  {
    for($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++)
    {
      $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
      echo "
        <table border='0', width='1000', align='center'>
        <tr>
        <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Theme</font></th>
        <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Locus_Id</font></th>
        <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene_Symbol</font></th>
        <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene_Name</font></th>
        <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Synonyms</font></th>
        <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Chromosome</font></th>
        <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene Summary</font></th>
        <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Homologene_Id</font></th>
        </tr>
      ";

      echo "<tr bgcolor = '#D3D3D3'>";
      echo "<td align=center>";
      echo 'Inflammation'; 
      echo "</td>";

      $strName2 = $result["Locus_id"];
      $strLink2 = "<a href = 'infla_gene_go.php?gene_id=" . $result['Locus_id'] . "'>" . $strName2 . "</a>";
      echo "<td align=center><font color = 'black'>" . $strLink2 . "</font></td>";
      $strName1 = $result["Gene_symbol"];
      $strLink1 = "<a href = 'infla_gene_symbol.php?gene_symbol=" . $result['Gene_symbol'] . "'>" . $strName1 . "</a>";
      echo "<td align=center><font color = 'black'>" . $strLink1 . "</font></td>";
      echo "<td align=center><font color = 'black'>" . $result['Gene_name'] . "</font></td>";
      echo "<td align=center><font color = 'black'>" . $result['Synonymns'] . "</font></td>";
      echo "<td align=center><font color = 'black'>" . $result['Chromosome_no'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td height='50px'><div style='height:200px;  overflow:scroll;'><font color = 'black'>" . $result['Gene_summary'] . "</font></div></td>";
      $strName = $result["Homologene_id"];
      $strLink = "<a href = 'infla_homologene.php?homologene_id=" . $result['Homologene_id'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>"; 
      echo "<td align=center>" . $strLink . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
  }
  break;


case "stress_info":

  $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from stress_info where Gene_symbol = '$search'");
  $num_row=$sql->num_rows;

  if ($num_row == 0)
  {
    echo "<font color = 'red'>Gene not found in Stress.</font>";
  }
  else
  {
    for($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++)
    {
      $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
      echo "<table border='0', width='1000', align='center'>
      <tr>
      <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Theme</font></th>
      <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Locus_Id</font></th>
      <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene_Symbol</font></th>
      <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene_Name</font></th>
      <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Synonyms</font></th>
      <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Chromosome</font></th>
      <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene Summary</font></th>
      <th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Homologene_Id</font></th>
      </tr>";

      echo "<tr bgcolor = '#D3D3D3'>";
      echo "<td align=center>";
      echo 'Stress'; 
      echo "</td>";
      $strName2 = $result["Locus_id"];
      $strLink2 = "<a href = 'stress_gene_go.php?gene_id=" . $result['Locus_id'] . "'>" . $strName2 . "</a>";
      echo "<td align=center>" . $strLink2 . "</td>";
      $strName1 = $result["Gene_symbol"];
      $strLink1 = "<a href = 'stress_gene_symbol.php?gene_symbol=" . $result['Gene_symbol'] . "'>" . $strName1 . "</a>";
      echo "<td align=center>" . $strLink1 . "</td>";
      echo "<td align=center>" . $result['Gene_name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td align=center>" . $result['Synonymns'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td align=center>" . $result['Chromosome_no'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td height='50px'><div style='height:200px;  overflow:scroll;'>" . $result['Gene_summary'] . "</div></td>";
      //$strName = $result['FirstName'] . " " . $result['LastName']
      $strName = $result["Homologene_id"];

      // Create a link to person.php with the id-value in the URL
      // $strLink = "<a href = 'person.php?id = " . $result['id'] . "'>" . $strNavn . "</a>";
      $strLink = "<a href = 'stress_homologene.php?homologene_id=" . $result['Homologene_id'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>";

      echo "<td align=center>" . $strLink . "</td>";
      // echo "<td align=center>" . $result['PMID'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";

      break;  //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that    
    }
  }
```

above is the code for fetching data from tables.
please help me friends, ma boss going to kill me.....
thanx in advance.

Comment: if it works for multiple tables it will work for all tables, what is your question?

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: your option selected="selected" is creating problem in select all. Try to print_r($_POST['table']);

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 it is different related to fetching data. Previous question was related to jquery.

Comment: my question is if i am selecting multiple using ctrl button, it is giving proper output, but when i give select all option it doesnt give result, then what should i put in value = " " for select all option 
 <option value="?" selected="selected">select all</option>
to put that option in switch case and fetch data from all tables matching to the search term

Comment: I think the OP want to fetch data with all the selected options by query. The OP need a query with WHERE condition

Comment: Can you please post your PHP Code.

Comment: I think OP wants to use additional `if (selectedValue == 'all') change selected value to array with all tables to emulate selection of all options in html` in server-side code

Comment: use print_r($_POST['table']). to print the result you got after selecting  all options from list. I think there is problem in posted data.

Comment: And post the result here.

Comment: it is not working dear :(

Answer (score -1):

There may be more than one way to do it. Your question is not clear to me, correct me if I'm wrong.
If you want to select columns from more than one table you may try using `UNION` operator. Add a 'all' option in your select box.

```
<option value='all'>All</option>
```

First check for the option value and if it's equal to 'all' just use the `UNION` operator to club your results from different SQL queries.

For example i have 2 tables:

Table1

```
-----------------------
id  |  name  |  age   |
-----------------------
1   |  boo   |  12    |
-----------------------
2   |  boom  |  13    |
-----------------------
```

Table2

```
-----------------------
id  |  name  |  age   |
-----------------------
1   |  rofl  |  14    |
-----------------------
2   |  lol   |  15    |
-----------------------
```

Now `SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2` will result in something like this:

```
-----------------------
id  |  name  |  age   |
-----------------------
1   |  boo   |  12    |
-----------------------
2   |  boom  |  13    |
-----------------------
1   |  rofl  |  14    |
-----------------------
2   |  lol   |  15    |
-----------------------
```

Basically you just need to check for the Option Value and if it's equal to all just club all of your results from those SQL queries using `UNION` operator.

For more information visit http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp